# Proper way to update ImageView in a RemoteViews?

Tags: android, android-appwidget, remoteview

I'm trying to fetch an image from a remote URL and put it into an ImageView.  The ImageView itself is within an app widget, so from my current understanding that means it is encapsulated within a RemoteViews and isn't really handled directly.

But I can never get the app widget to display an image.  I'm fetching the image as a Bitmap from a remote URL using an AsyncTask extension, and it seems like the image is being fetched OK (a non-null bitmap is returned anyway), though as yet I can't display it to confirm.

I reckon I must be using the wrong method to actually update the app widget's ImageView.

Here is all the relevant code:

layout/new_app_widget.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

relevant bit from NewAppWidget.java:

```
public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

...

static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int appWidgetId) {

    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);

    String strURL = "http://example.com/YqLOSfr4.png";

    new ImageFetchAsyncTask(strURL, R.id.imageView).execute();
    // ^^^^^
    // in the above, I pass the URL and the id of the imageview, fetch
    // the bitmap, and in the onPostExecute() method I use
    // setImageViewBitmap(viewId, bitmap) to load the bitmap into the imageview
    // 
    // I don't have the code to hand, but I can provide it.  For now, someone
    // may be able to tell me somewhere else I'm doing something wrong

    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mike.widgetapptest" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        android:debuggable="true"
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".NewAppWidget" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/new_app_widget_info" />
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you just need to use 3rd party  library that will manage it's own life cycle in background.
you just need to provide the image url to your network image view

Comment: Danial, since I'm new to this, do you think you could expand a little on your comment?  What 3rd party library, and what do you mean by providing the image url to the network image view?

Comment: did you know how to use library project in android?

Comment: not yet but I soon will!

Comment: ok first download volley jar file and place it inside your android application libs folder.

Comment: i am giving you a link 

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/
you just need to follow 

step 2 ,step 3 , step 8

in your current code. from that link

Comment: hmm ok i'll have to do this later because I don't have access to my Android Studio environment right now.  What 3rd party library in particular?  Any clues so that I can try later?  It seems odd to me that it should be so complicated (and require 3rd party libraries) just to do something so basic... fetching an image and putting it into an imageview?

Comment: 3rd party library is basically the code of jar file in the form of project.

jar file is basically precompiled file you can't modify it.
for flexibility the compile the library project after you modify it and get the new jar

Comment: OK thanks I'll take a look.  So volley provides a simpler way of fetching data (such as bitmaps).  Going back to my code that relates more to the app widget and the remoteviews, is there anything fundamentally wrong in what I'm doing?  Once I have the bmp, I'm using setImageViewBitmap(int, android.graphics.Bitmap) (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) to load the bitmap into the imageview (passing the imageview id into it).

Comment: Actually, have I slipped up because of the async nature of the image fetch?  I fetch the bmp in an async method, and then immediately after that (see my code above) I write "appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);", which is I assume what *actually* causes the imageview to be refreshed?  But if the image hasn't yet been fetched, then the refresh won't do anything? If so, how do I cause the refresh to happen *after* the image is fetched?

Comment: Woohoo!  I can confirm that it was indeed a classic beginner's error, in doing something immediately following an async task, expecting the async task to have completed.  So I moved what depends on the async completion into the onPostExecute() method of the async task, and voila... image displayed in my app widget!  I will definitely look into the volley library as well... anything to make basic network calls less like pulling teeth would be most welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic beginner's error... I was attempting to do something immediately following an async task, expecting the async task to have completed.  So I moved what depends on the result of the async task into the onPostExecute() method of the async task, and voila... image displayed in my app widget!

Comment: I thought I might lose reputation for answering my own question!

Comment: Nope, perfectly valid!